# MIL-HDBK-217F-N2 asks for # of gates and/or transistors

Tags: reliability

New to the whole reliability prediction using MIL-217F, was wondering whether anyone had an advise/suggestion/best-practice/wisdom on how to determine the number of gates and/or transistors from a datasheet. For example, got a FPGA component (XC7S25-2CSGA225I), and based on the MIL-217F I need # of transistors to determine the failure rate for this component.

I have other IC components that I need to know the number of gates, but as far as I can tell none of the datasheet provided by the mfts/suppliers have such information. Perhaps, not being an electrical engineering doesn't make this process any easier. Would welcome any advice.

Comment: It's quite possible that Xilinx has their own failure rate prediction based on their knowledge and characterization of the part, but it's not shared in the datasheet by default (possibly by special request, or under NDA). You may want to reach out to your Xilinx FAE, if you are working with one.